# Mosquitto Auth Plugin wildcards topics not working

Tags: mosquitto

I've setup mosquitto auth plugin in my server and configured MongoDB as backend. I have a collection like:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5d696b3a23bb5613fea4c2c0"),
    "username" : "user1",
    "password" : "PBKDF2$sha256$901$jvmyoNAi2GYOELnS$8syPnDylOIpxInBlL14GOLbyAnFHI1bl",
    "superuser" : false,
    "topics" : {
        "article/#" : "r",
        "article/+/comments" : "rw",
        "ballotbox" : "w"
    }
}
```

A sub:

```
mosquitto_sub -h mqtt.myserver.com -t "article/#" -u user1 -P 123
```

A pub:

```
mosquitto_pub -h mqtt.myserver.com -t "article/1/comments" -m "testing..." -u user1 -P 123
```

Or

```
mosquitto_pub -h mqtt.myserver.com -t "article" -m "testing..." -u user1 -P 123
```

this is the plugin log:

```
-- mosquitto_auth_unpwd_check(user1)
-- ** checking backend mongo
-- getuser(user1) AUTHENTICATED=1 by mongo
-- mosquitto_auth_acl_check(..., client id not available, user1, article/1/comments, MOSQ_ACL_WRITE)
-- aclcheck(user1, article/1/comments, 2) trying to acl with mongo
-- aclcheck(user1, article/1/comments, 2) AUTHORIZED=1 by mongo
--  Cached  [C909F3664285F35139ED8836043853B5C5F70616] for (client id not available,user1,2)
```

In any case, when I subscribe to wildcard topics, I can't get any messages.

However, without wildcards it works perfectly.

Tested before enabling the plugin, Mosquitto works perfectly, which leads me to debug only the plugin and its particularities.

**EDIT 1**

The problem occurs only when Mosquitto is compiled with WITH_WEBSOCKETS=yes otherwise it works.

If WITH_WEBSOCKETS=yes and WebSockets not configured in conf file, wildcard doesn’t work at all, only MOSQ_ACL_WRITE appears on log.

If WITH_WEBSOCKETS=yes and WebSockets configured in conf file, it does work but with certain intermittence and a HUGE delay publishing and receiving the message.

**EDIT 2**

> Mosquitto: 1.5.8
>
> Mosquitto Auth: 0.13
>
> LibWebSockets: 3.2.0

What am I missing with the WebSockets configuration ?

Couldn't find any topic related.

Any help appreciated.

Comment: https://github.com/jpmens/mosquitto-auth-plug/issues/405 ?

Comment: it was covered in late version. 0.13, the latest. What is weird is about sockets. If enabled works, but with a very long delay.

Comment: That Issue is from March 2019 this year, 0.13 was released in Nov 2018

Comment: hmm I should not work till late night. I will try to build it from source and get last commit. Thanks to point out.

Comment: In fact it was a bug. jpmens repo is out of dated, I got the good one here https://github.com/whendonkiesfly/mosquitto-auth-plug thank you @hardillb to point good insights